# How to dim a light source's effect on selected materials using light groups in the compositor?

Tags: compositing-nodes, cryptomatte, light-groups

In Blender 3.2.2 I have multiple light groups to light up a scene of objects. One light group in particular(HL group) is used just to highlight a singular object. I wish to dim the effectiveness of the HL group on the other objects/surfaces using cryptomatte in the compositor.

Answer (score 0):

**[image: strong text]**

1. Enable Cycles Render Engine.
2. Add Cryptomatte materials pass.
3. Add Light Groups and assign light sources to light groups.
4. Render then edit compositing nodes to look like the image above.

In this example, I dimmed the white light source's effect on all objects except the middle monkey. I didn't want to dim the white light on the middle monkey. In the cryptomatte node, I added the Monkey2 surface for the middle monkey to the MatteID so it is not included with the objects effected by the dimming.